# Wordpress Jquery Page Completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, cookies

I am developing an E-learning site.
I want my registered students to get this feature when they are reading a course content:
a completion button locating right beside each paragraph, and what it does is it makes the paragraph font colours change, so these students can always login in the future and the browser remember where they should start to continued the readings.

For example:
[image]

Changing these font colour is not too hard for me to do as I do front-end development, but I am confused when its relating to database/cookie? Please share with your experience.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set one flag(column) to database table & value of these column is (1/0) means completed or not.when user click on checkbox change value of that column to 1 (completed) & when user login to there account you have to display his/her account as per this flag value means based on 1/0 value display paragraph font color..